# javaScript changing parent menu item when child item is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to the javaScript and it would be very helpful for me if somebody could be so glad to give me some directions how to perform that. I'm creating website in Joomla 3 and I need to stylize the menu in a way that when a child menu item is active the parent item should change the background colour. I included the .js link into the head of the index.php file of my template. But I'm struggling second day with the desired script.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="gf-menu l1">
    <li class="item128 parent">
        <a class="item" href"services">Services<span class="border-fixer"></span>::after</a>
        <div class="dropdown columns-1">
            <div class="column col1">
                <ul class="l2">
                    <li class ="item1"><a class="item" href="submenu-01">Submenu1</a></li>
                    <li class ="item2"><a class="item" href="submenu-02">Submenu2</a></li>
                    <li class ="item3"><a class="item" href="submenu-03">Submenu3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And that's it my CSS for it:

```
.gf-menu .dropdown{
    border: 1px solid transparent; 
    border-radius:0; 
    background-color:#a9a9a9; 
    padding:10% 0; 
    width:100%;
    text-shadow:none;
    font-size:85%;
}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item1.active.last {background-color:#abcf39;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item2.active.last {background-color:#f39512;}
.gf-menu.l1 li.item3.active.last {background-color:#f16e68;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click on the `<li>` element and want to affect the parent you can use the `.parent()` method to target the parent element. The question is which one do you want to target. If it's the `div` which contains the `<ul>` you will have to access the parent of a parent. For example if the `<li>` has a class `item` as you stated in your question, you can do

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
    var clickedLiElement = $(this);
    var parentHoldingUl = clickedLiElement.parent().parent();

    //now you can do whatever you want with both of them, for example
    clickedLiElement.addClass('active');
    parentHoldingUl.css('background-color', 'green');
});
```

Update based on comments:

A slightly shorter version, which does what you specified in the comments

```
$('.item').on('click', function(){
    $(this).css('background-color', '#5512F3');
    $(this).parent().parent().css('background-color', '#5512F3');
    $(this).siblings().css('background-color', '#AB99D5');
});
```

This should turn the clicked LI element and it's parent DIV dark blue and the clicked elemnent's siblings light blue.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I'm trying to make something like that:
"Our Services"(item128 parent)
  -->"Item1" (if this is active- It goes dark blue itslef + the parent item; the rest of the drop down goes light blue)
  -->"Item2"
  -->"Item3"

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly - the active LI element goes dark blud as well as the wrapper DIV and the other LIs change to light blue.. right? If I got it correct, I can update the answer.

Comment: Yes, it's correct only the active LI element and the parent item goes dark blue, the rest of the LIs goes light blue. I really appreciate your attendance. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Updated. Please tell me if it works for you, if not, creating a jsFiddle would be awesome - I'll try to help further.

Comment: Thank you for that, really get me in proper direction, but as I mentioned previously I'm dummy with the javaScript and I need some more time to configure how this could be working for me, when I have some results I will share the entire solution here! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help at least a bit. Cheers!